# Переадресация в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Доброго времени суток.
Вот такой вопрос:
Создал я значит правила из регулярных выражений для того, что бы привести URL в порядок.
Как сделать так, что бы шла сразу переадресация на новые URL.
Вот пример правила:
RewriteRule ^news-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ shop.php?uid=$1&action=news_list&m=news
возможно ли не ковыряясь в шаблоне сайта реализовать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} shop.php?uid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&action=news_list&m=news$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /news-%1? [R=301,L]